# How to set "ON" condition with "includes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I implement following three models.

```
# app/model/foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hoge
  has_many :bars
end

# app/model/hoge.rb
class Hoge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :foo
end

# app/model/bar.rb
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

I would like to get "foo" records with "bars" and "hoge" are eager loaded.
In addition, I have to set "ON" condition of "LEFT OUTER JOIN" like following.

```
SELECT *
FROM foos
LEFT OUTER JOIN bars  ON bars.foo_id = foo.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN hoges ON hoges.id = foo.hoge_id AND (foo.name = "name")
where foo.country = "japan"
```

I tried by using "includes" and "references".
But, "includes" doesn't accept condtion of "ON"

(accept only table name...)

```
Foo
  .includes(:bars)
  .includes(:hoge)
  .where(country: "japan")
  .references(:bar)
  .references(:hoge)
```

How can I set condition of "ON"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `joins` method to customize the join conditions and `includes` to eager load the records, here is the doc link http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins

```
Foo.
  joins(:bars).
  joins("LEFT JOIN hoges h ON h.id = foos.hoge_id AND (foos.name = 'name')").
  where(country: "japan").
  includes(:bars).
  includes(:hoge)
```

Comment: I tried but this query doesn't work well. if "includes" is used, "references" is need to be used. but, if "join" is used with "reference", "reference" doesn't work well(eager load doesn't work)...

Comment: @user4252489 I assume you are using the latest rails (active_record) ? Actually I tested with a new rails codebase with your db schema and it worked.

Comment: @user4252489 And, if you are using an old rails (active_record) version, I suggest you checking the doc of `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#joins`.

Comment: @user4252489 It would be great if you could create a sample rails codebase (with the version you are using) and reproduce the problem, I could help you from there.

Comment: Sorry.. I used old rails , I try after updating rails to 4.1.0. query works well! Thank you!